# Problems with JFileChooser in java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a JFileChooser to JPanel. Sometimes it works properly and sometimes it shows just the JPanel without the JFileChooser dialogue box. Now i actually don't know what to do . Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code(It is a method):

```
public  File chooseFileFromComputer(){

    methodPanel = new JPanel();
    methodPanel.setLayout(null);


    methodFrame = new JFrame();
    methodFrame.setTitle("File Chooser");
    methodFrame.setVisible(true);

    BufferedImage removeJavaImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    methodFrame.setIconImage(removeJavaImage);

    methodLabel = new JLabel("Choose a file: ");
    methodLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 20);
    methodPanel.add(methodLabel);

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fileChooser.setBounds(10, 35, 550, 500 );
    fileChooser.setVisible(true);
    add(fileChooser);
       /**
     * Action Events                                                    #********AE*******#
    **/

    fileChooser.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
           selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
           methodFrame.setVisible(false);     
        }  else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
            methodFrame.setVisible(false);
        }
      }
    });

    //End of Action Events                                              #________AE_______#


    methodPanel.add(fileChooser);
    methodFrame.setContentPane(methodPanel);
    methodFrame.setResizable(false);
    methodFrame.setSize(600, 600);
    methodFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    return selectedFile;
}
```

Comment: Please see 2nd edit to answer. A lot to pick apart here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using a null layout and calling `setBounds(...)` on your components. While this may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's.
2. add your components to the JFrame, and only then call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame.
3. It doesn't look like you should be using a JFrame at all if you are setting it visible and invisible. Perhaps you really want to use a JDialog or even a free standing JFileChooser dialog.

---

**Edit**
You are adding the JFileChooser to more than one container:

```
  add(fileChooser); // ******************* here *************

  fileChooser.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
      private File selectedFile;

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
      if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
         selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
         methodFrame.setVisible(false);     
      }  else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
          methodFrame.setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  });

  methodPanel.add(fileChooser); // ******** here *******
```

You can't do this. Only add it to ***one*** container, else it may not show correctly or show at all.

---

**Edit 2**

You're returning the wrong result from your method. You return the selectedFile variable, but do so before it is ever set since it is set by the ActionListener which is called long *after* this method returns.

Solution: again, don't use a JFrame here where a modal JDialog would work much better. If you used a modal dialog and returned *after* the ActionListener is done, your code would work.

---

**Edit 3**
But again for my money, I'd just use a JFileChooser as a modal dialog. For example:

```
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose a File");

  // don't use null in the method below but rather a reference to your current GUI
  int response = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     System.out.println(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JPanel  - `methodPanel` has null layout   `methodPanel.setLayout(null);` try it with  for example with `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly about your class wherether extends jpanel or not , but you should add filechooser to methodPanel together with label. I tested your code is ok except actionPerform.

```
methodPanel.add(fielChooser);
```

I suggest, just try it.